# How to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}x \lceil\tfrac 1 x\rceil =1$?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x \lceil\tfrac 1 x\rceil =1$$

Showing a graph from desmos
[image]

Comment: The command is `\lceil` and `\rceil`.

Comment: Simply, "\lceil \rceil" ($\lceil \rceil$).  Here, though, use "\left\lceil \right\rceil" ($\left\lceil \right\rceil$) since they need to vertically stretch for the fraction.

Comment: Clearly the limit does not exist, since it becomes arbitrarily large ($\lceil \frac ax \rceil \geqslant \frac ax \to \infty$ as $x\to0$)

Comment: My bad, that should be have x before the greatest function

Comment: And also a 1 instead of a

Comment: Try sketching a graph of that function near $x=0$.

Comment: Well $[\frac 1x] \le \frac 1x$ so $x [\frac 1x] \le 1$.

Comment: @fleablood : When $x = -2$, your first inequality is backwards...

Comment: As an aside: your graph suggests you are looking to use the squeeze theorem.  As a practical matter, since the bounds appear to be linear, it is probably easier to handle the $x \rightarrow 0^+$ and $x \rightarrow 0^-$ halves of the limit separately (so you can swap the roles of the upper- and lower-bounding functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is easiest to use a change of variables, $z=\frac{1}{x}$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x \lceil\tfrac 1 x\rceil = \lim_{z \to \pm \infty} \frac{\lceil z \rceil}{z}$$

Then use the fact that for $z>0$:
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{z} = \frac{z-1}{z} \le \frac{\lceil z \rceil}{z} \le \frac{z+1}{z} = 1 + \frac{1}{z} $$
For $z<0$ you have the same thing with the inequalities reversed. Either way, it is [sandwiched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) between two things with limit $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $0<|x|\leq1$. It is possible.

Let $n$ denote natural number.

We know that $(0,1]$ is a disjoint union of $\{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

It means that $(0,1] = \cdots \sqcup (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}] \sqcup (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}] \sqcup (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$.

**First Case : $x \rightarrow 0+$**

If $\frac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}$, then $[\frac{1}{x}] = n$ 
and $\frac{n}{n+1} < x [\frac{1}{x}] \leq 1$.

$x[\frac{1}{x}] \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which means that as $x \rightarrow 0+$.

**Second Case : $x \rightarrow 0-$**

If $-\frac{1}{n+1} \geq x > -\frac{1}{n}$, then $[\frac{1}{x}] = -(n+1)$ and $1 \leq x [\frac{1}{x}] < \frac{n+1}{n}$.

$x[\frac{1}{x}] \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which means that as $x \rightarrow 0-$.

Comment: There is a little something reversed here.  You are given $x$ and need to find a suitablle $n$.  You have written it the other way around: "after picking $n$, hope that it has the right relationship with $x$".  So a fair question is, given a particular $x$, why does $n$ exist?

Comment: Thank you. I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Let So $x \to 0$ and $x < 1$ then $\frac 1x \to \infty$ and $\frac 1x > 1$.

Let $n_x$ be a natural number so that $n_x \le \frac 1x < n_x+1$.

$\lfloor \frac 1x \rfloor = n_x$.

So $xn_x \le x*\frac 1x < 1\le x(n_x+1)$

$xn_x \le 1 < xn_x + x$

So... what is the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ again?

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta$ so that $|x -a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \epsilon$ then

And if $|x-0| = x <\delta = \epsilon$ then $xn_x \le 1 < xn_x + x < xn_x +\epsilon$.

And therefore $0\le 1-xn_x < x < \epsilon$

And that's that.

Comment: Since $n_x \geq 0$, you have addressed "$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}$", not the two-sided limit.

Comment: Argh.  Obviously not.

Comment: It's done the same in cases.  I'll add to it in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the ceiling function you have

- $x>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} \leq \left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil < \frac{1}{x} +1 \Rightarrow 1\leq x\left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil < 1+x$
  $$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0^+}x\left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil = 1$$
- $x<0 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x}+1 > \left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil \geq \frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow 1+x < x\left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil \leq 1$
  $$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0^-}x\left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil = 1$$